# Sending image posted on PHP server to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the following PHP code to get images uploaded from mobile devices:

```
<?php
   $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
   $binary=base64_decode($base);
   header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
   $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
   fwrite($file, $binary);
   fclose($file);?>
```

I want to send these images directly to Amazon's S3 service. Do I have to write the JPEG on disk each time? Can't I just send the binary to Amazon S3 and let it generate the JPEG? I'm worried the local write will hammer my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using s3fs to mount your S3 bucket as a local drive on your server.  You could then write files directly to that mount location.  You can also specify a local directory to be used as a cache for the s3fs mount to speed things up if you want your application to be able to read these files.

Here is the link to s3fs Google Code page: http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/

Comment: Seems like a great idea. Does that mean I don't need the AWS PHP SDK? If so, could you give me a few pointers on how to mount the bucket on my server and how to post an image into it?

Comment: Yes, for this purpose you would have no need of the SDK, as from the PHP perspective this would just be local storage. I have added a link to the s3fs project site, you can get the installation procedures from the wiki there.